# Redirect/Rewrite after basic authentication

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication, openhab

First sorry for my bad English.

So I have an Openhab system on my raspberry PI with Apache.
I have A basic authentication with two groups Admin and Users and I want to redirect Users the open the Landing page to redirect after Loggin with the Basic auth to the UI page. The problem is I can't use a PHP script.

So I tried to redirect the Users with the .htaccess

`.htaccess:`

```
<Location />
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =Elias
RewriteRule ^start/index /basicui/app
</Location>
```

But so it doesn't work and I haven't found anything that I help with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/start\/index$
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =Username
        RewriteRule .* http://openhab.clubdrei.com/basicui/app [R=302,L]
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =Username
        RewriteRule .* http://openhab.clubdrei.com/basicui/app [R=302,L]
```